# Running Python Scripts Outside of IDLE

Tags: python, windows, terminal

1- i want someone to help with this part

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/appendixb/

about Running Python Scripts Outside of IDLE and sending command line args .

2- i converted my code to .exe  by pyinstaller  ; what's the difference between this and running it

as a script .

3-how scripts are done . i see experienced people says :"i made a script to do something for me " how is that done >?

*i'm a beginner so try to make answers simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering about command line arguments, look into the "argparse" library https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html.

The difference in the .exe and the normal script is that that the .exe versions (conventionally) are able to be redistributed to other sytems that don't have python installed whilst still being able to run the script. If you're only making the script for yourself the only real benefit is that you dont have to enter your IDE (code editor) every time you want to run the code, however if it's still in development then you'd have to compile the code every time you made a modification if you're wanting to run the code as an executable, which is very impractical.

Your third part is very, very vague. Python can be very versatile and i recommend you continue looking at the automatetheboringstuff.com website if you're interested in making scripts that can complete repetitive activities (although i must strongly advise you against using scripts maliciously).